# How to use "what is more"?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

Just curious if "what is more" is basically the same as "furthermore". It seems to be an expression that creates emphasis, right? How about the following sentence:

> I am a great admirer of her films; what's more I've seen each one several times.

Comment: This expression is usually *what's more*, though *what is more* is possible.

Answer (score 13):

*What's more* is an expression that's used when you want to emphasize that the next action or fact is more or as important as the one mentioned.

> War doesn't bring peace; what's more, it brings more chaos.

Or your example.

Comment: Extremely helpful, Noah!

Answer (score 7):

*Furthermore* and *what's more* are not exactly synonymous, and are generally found in different contexts.

*Furthermore* is a transition word that tells the reader to expect an addition to previously stated facts or arguments. It does not imply that the new fact or argument is more important.

*Furthermore* is most often found in formal written contexts.

*What's more* also alerts the recipient to expect a new fact or argument, but it tends to imply that this new fact or argument is more important than those previously stated.

*What's more* is much more common in informal spoken contexts than in formal written contexts.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification. This is my first time on this site and I will definitely be back!